# Variável Não Altera Dentro de Uma Factory Function

Tags: javascript

Bom dia.

Eu estava estudando um pouco mais sobre Factory Function e não entendi o motivo da variável *img* não estar sendo alterada.

```js
const imgs  = () => {
    let img = [];
    return {
        addImg: (photo) => img = [...img, photo],
        img
    };
};
const images = imgs();
images.addImg('akskaskssk');
images.addImg('aloaloalo');
console.log(images.img); // []
```

É possível a variável ser modificada a cada chamada do método *addImg*?

Desde já, agradeço pela atenção!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não dá certo porque e um [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), é uma função que guarda consigo o ambiente léxico a qual a definiu.

No momento de sua definição, a função referenciada por `addImg` continha em seu escopo de definição uma variável `img` a referencia para um array vazio. A cada chamada dessa função o que o código `img = [...img, photo]` faz é apenas mudar a referência interna de um array vazio para outro array, as referências externas continuam apontando para o mesmo array vazio.
Ou seja terminou a função a referência interna sumiu e não foi utilizada e as referencias externas continuam apontando para o array vazio.

O que você deve fazer é modificar a composição do array sem modificar as referências. Para isso pode usar um [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Veja o exemplo:

```js
const imgs = () => {
  let img = [];
  return {
    //Modifica o array mantendo a referência.
    addImg: (photo) => img.splice(img.length, null, photo),
    img
  };
};
const images = imgs();
images.addImg('akskaskssk');
images.addImg('aloaloalo');
console.log(images.img);
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi realizando tipo um *getter*, retornando o valor da varíavel.

```js
const imgs  = () => {
  let img = [];
  return {
      addImg: (photo) => img = [...img, photo],
      getImg: () => img
  };
};
const images = imgs();
images.addImg('akskaskssk');
images.addImg('aloaloalo');
console.log(images.getImg()); // ["akskaskssk", "aloaloalo"]
```

Comment: e qual é a utilidade prática disso?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo é padrão de factory. Normalmente é usado em conjunto de uma fonte automatizada de recursos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, voei kkk, sou leigo no assunto.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, você não voou não. O uso prático não está muito intuitivo porque acho que é um exemplo simplificado. Nesse caso eu acredito, suposição minha, que esse factory vai ser usado em código mais complexo que retorne listas de elementos HTML `<img>` vindos de uma solicitação a um servidor, o servidor envia o JSON e a função monta as tags. O autor deixou dessa forma apenas para facilitar a compreensão da pergunta e eliminando detalhes da implementação que não afetaria o resultado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, valeu a explicação